# Get browser cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm trying to get the browser cookies using:
`browser.cookies.getAll()` but I always get this error in the console log instead:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: browser is not defined

here's my code:

```
  var gettingAll = browser.cookies.getAll({
                     url: "url"
                    });
  console.log(gettingAll);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the following...

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie

```
function getCookie(cname) {
  var name = cname + "=";
  var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
  var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
  for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
        c = c.substring(1);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
        return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
  }
  return "";
}
```

Edit: fixed code block.

Comment: what's the difference between your code and this code?

var x = document.cookie;
alert(x);

because it gives the same result!

Comment: @MAk alert x will give you every cookie, the code above will give u a certain cookie, so you can store name and surname in the cookie and if u just wanted name it would be var name = getCookie("name");

Answer (score 1):

to get the **url** value u can use this solution :

```
    var cookiesMap = document.cookie.split(";").map( value => {
        var val =value.split("=")
        var obj = { "key" : val[0], "value" : val[1] }
        return obj;
        });

    for( var i = 0 ; i < cookiesMap.length ; i++ ){
        if( cookiesMap[i].key==="url"){
            console.log(cookiesMap[i].value);
        }
    }
```

hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

`browser` is indeed undefined. It's not a native JavaScript object.

You should use `document.cookie` ([see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie)) instead.